# Authorization header on Axis 1.4 Service

Tags: java, web-services, call, axis, stub

I have an old webservice created with Axis 1.4 that i need to consume. To make it work, on request header must be added the following token

Authorization: Basic {codifiedUsername}

Using soapui i dont have any issue, but when i try to add the authorization token into axis service call, service response with error, just like when i dont set codifiedUsername into request header on soapui

I´m using the following code trying to add the token Authorization: Basic {codifiedUsername}, to the header

```
String targetNamespace = "http://www.mysrevice/services/MyService";
String serviceName = "MyService";
String portName = "MyService";
String wsdlURL = "http://xxx.xx.xx.x:8080/idws2/services/MyService?wsdl";
QName qnameService = new QName(targetNamespace, serviceName);
QName qnamePort = new QName(targetNamespace, portName);
ServiceFactory factory = (ServiceFactory) ServiceFactory.newInstance();        
Service service = (Service)factory.createService(new URL(wsdlURL),qnameService);      
QName qnameOperation = new QName(targetNamespace, "validate");        
Call call = (Call)service.createCall(qnamePort, qnameOperation);           
String user="235654321";
byte[] bUser=usuario.getBytes();
String encoded=Base64.encode(bUser);
System.out.println("encoded user: "+encoded);                    
org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement header = new org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement("http://myservice.com","MyServiceHeade r");
SOAPElement node = header.addChildElement("Authorization:");
node.addTextNode("Basic "+encoded);
call.addHeader(header);
Object[] params = {"6677","6778","001","trrtr"};
call.addHeader(header);
String response = (String)call.invoke(params);
```

I also created the webservice stub to see if stub does have any method to pass the header with authorization info, but i dont know so much about axis. This is the code that i have to call the same method

```
MyService myService = new MyServiceLocator();
MyServiceSoapBindingStub stub;              
stub = new MyServiceSoapBindingStub(new     URL(myService.getMyServiceAddress()),myService);               
String result=stub.validate("6677","6778","001","trrtr");
```

So i need to know how correctly set authorization token on service call or service stub, using java Axis 1.4

Thanks

Comment: Is `usuario.getBytes()` supposed to be `user.getBytes()`?  Also, from my experience, what is expected for Basic auth is a Base64 encoded string of `username:password` rather than `username`; but I only see the username being passed to encode.

Comment: User is suplied but i ommited by simplicity, also namespace and service real name. User codified is the same for java code and soapui request. On soap ui headers the request is sent with Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX

Comment: In no way am I trying to be condescending but I'm not sure that answers my question or addresses my following point; I don't understand what you mean by what you said.
If you're saying that the code you posted doesn't necessarily reflect what is happening during your actual application, then it's hard to help find what's going wrong.  If you can, post a MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example).

Comment: The code create an axis call using a wsdl, code on base64 an username, create parameters, try create a header to add "Authorization: Basic {codedUsername}",add header to service call, and call a service method. I ommited the real names ´cause is confidencial information, i only need to know how correctly set the header with the authorization token

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  I would point to my original comment, as far as I have ever found with `REST` an `Authorization: Basic` header is formed like the following: `Authorization: Basic {codedUsernamePassword}` where `{codedUsernamePassword}` is a `Base64` encoded `String` that follows the following format: `username:password`.  I'd suggest trying that.

Comment: I know that, the thing that i need to know is how to set it using Axis 1.4, ´cause is old technology and i´ve been unable to get a good example that works

Answer (score 0):

Setting an Auth header element for Axis 1.4 should look a little like this:

```
SOAPHeaderElement auth = new SOAPHeaderElement(url,"Authentication");
SOAPHeaderElement user = new SOAPHeaderElement(url,"User", "string");
SOAPHeaderElement pass = new SOAPHeaderElement(url,"Password", "string");
auth.addChild(user);
auth.addChild(pass);
// add to Call object ...
```

This should work...then just add to the call object like you are with your existing `SOAPHeaderElement`.

Comment: Thanks Susannah,so you tell me that something like this should work

SOAPHeaderElement auth = new SOAPHeaderElement(url,"Authentication");   
SOAPHeaderElement user = new SOAPHeaderElement(url,"Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);                    
auth.addChild(user);
call.addHeader(auth);                    
String response = (String)call.invoke(params);  
Where url is service namespace url

Code is fine?

Comment: Yes, from my understanding, that should fix it.  If this works out, please remember to accept my answer! :D

Comment: Sadly for me didn´t work, calling service with your advice is the same that with soapui when i dont set the header with 'Authorization' token, also  tried only setting the token with 'Authorization' on the call object, with the same result. Thanks

Comment: Seeing as this is your webservice, do you have a way of watching what is happening on its end when it receives this request?  It might be helpful to see what it's seeing from this so it can be compared to what is being sent by SoapUI.

Comment: Today i´m gonna search a way to do that, but i see in soap ui is that http header is where Authorization token is sent, yesterday i found an example where using Axis 1.4 authorization token is sent using mimeheaders, but didnt test